# Meaning of has had in sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

I can not comprehend the usage of has had in the following sentence.

> The party **has had** no qualms about polarizing electorate along the religious lines.

Comment: Perhaps it would hep if you gave us some more context and say what you find difficult about it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [present perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect) sentence. *Has* is an auxiliary verb, and *had* is the past participle of *have*.

Comment: "the second 'have'" is the main verb

Comment: does second have mean to say "to express",the actual meaning?

Comment: the first verb is an auxiliary verb (adds functional or grammatical meaning), the second verb conveys the action of possessing (to have = to possess)

Comment: thank you for clarifying that

Answer (score 1):

"has had" is an example of the present perfect tense of the verb "to have".

**Has** is working as an auxiliary verb, third person singular conjugation of the verb "to have" - it has no particular meaning of its own here. It's the word we use to form this particular tense in English.

**Had** is the past participle form of the verb "to have".

The present perfect tense is formed using have/has + past participle.

We use the present perfect tense in English to talk about a past action that has consequences or continues in the present.

Also there are two errors in the sentence. It should be "**the** electorate", and "along religious lines".